# Weird image using samsung s10e with camera api2

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, cameraapi2

Phone: samsung s10e

Android 11

API Level 30

I made an app for android samsung s10e which takes an image using the camera api 2 in android.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary

I was able to take and save images.
But sometimes the camera makes some weird looking images like the one below:

[image: Bad Image]

but it should look like this

[image: Good Image]

I tried to deactivate some properties of the camera request like:

```
set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_VIDEO_STABILIZATION_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_VIDEO_STABILIZATION_MODE_OFF)
set(CaptureRequest.LENS_OPTICAL_STABILIZATION_MODE, CaptureRequest.LENS_OPTICAL_STABILIZATION_MODE_OFF)
set(CaptureRequest.DISTORTION_CORRECTION_MODE, CaptureRequest.DISTORTION_CORRECTION_MODE_OFF)
set(CaptureRequest.EDGE_MODE, CaptureRequest.EDGE_MODE_OFF)
set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_QUALITY, 100.toByte())
```

But it didn't help.

Am I doing something wrong here?
I would appreiciate any help!.
Thanks!

Mouhammad

Answer (score 1):

Are you setting off any vibrations (from notifications or similar) during your testing?  The bad images look like the vibrator activated during it.

Otherwise, it looks like optical image stabilization could be malfunctioning. Turning it off may not help, since the OIS magnets have to be activated no matter whether OIS is actively adjusting the lens, since otherwise the lens will just bounce around loosely.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
No. The vibrations were turned off, so I guess it is not the problem.
I tried it with many s10e smart phones and I got the same behavior.
It doesn't happens too often. But it still critical if I get such images.